# How to smooth sidebar with CSS in Laravel 5.7

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I seem to be having some issues with my sidebar animation. In my dashboard I have a chart with a table beneath it and if the table has more than 4 rows my sidebar animations are extremely jittery. I've tried to read some articles and add in some suggestions like adding translations and transitions, but my problem still exists.

Here is my NavBar blade:

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="sidebar-content">
    <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <img id="logo" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="" alt="User picture">
        <a href="/">App</a>
        <div id="close-sidebar">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="user-pic">
            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="" alt="User picture">
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
            @if(Auth::check()) {{Auth::user()->name}}
                @else John Smith
            @endif

            <span class="user-role">
                @if(Auth::check())
                    @php

                    @endphp
                @else
                    Guest
                @endif
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-header  -->

    <!-- sidebar-search  -->
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Queue/">
                    <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
                    <span>Queue</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Reports/">
                    <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>
                    <span>Reports</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Search/">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    <span>Search</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
</div>
<!-- sidebar-content  -->
<div class="sidebar-footer">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="/logout" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Dashboard Blade:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <table id="Dashtable" class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
                    <th scope="col">New Issue:</th>
                    <th scope="col">In Progress:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($campuses as $campus)
                    @php
                        $inProgress = 0;
                        $newIssue = 0;
                    @endphp
                    @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)

                    @endforeach
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <a class="campusLinks" href="">{{$campus->CampusName}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="counter">{{$newIssue}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="counter">{{$inProgress}}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And the accompanying css:

```
 /*----------------Table----------------*/
#Dashtable > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#Dashtable > thead {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}


#Dashtable {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    max-width: 65vw;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 65vw;
}

.counter {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: #131212 solid 1px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.campusLinks {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------page-wrapper----------------*/

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrapper .theme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .theme.chiller-theme {
  background: #1d1d1d;
}

/*----------------toggeled sidebar----------------*/

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper.toggled .page-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
}
/*----------------show sidebar button----------------*/
#show-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0px;
  width: 35px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.page-wrapper.toggled #show-sidebar {
  left: -40px;
}
/*----------------sidebar-wrapper----------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.sidebar-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And lastly the Jquery code that adds and removes classes:

```
$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
       $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
 });

 $("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
        $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
 });
```

If there's any recommended resources on how to create smooth animations that you would recommend I would really appreciate it

**EDIT**

Here is my updated CSS:

```
   /*----------------page-wrapper----------------*/

.page-wrapper {
  transition: all ease;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrapper .theme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .theme.chiller-theme {
  background: #1d1d1d;
}

/*----------------toggeled sidebar----------------*/

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
    transform: translateX(115%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(115%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper.toggled .page-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
}
/*----------------show sidebar button----------------*/
#show-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0px;
  width: 35px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.page-wrapper.toggled #show-sidebar {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-120%);
  transform: translateX(-120%);
}
/*----------------sidebar-wrapper----------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all ease;
}

.sidebar-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) is a great article on how to create smooth css animations.

tl;dr;

Basically try to use css properties which are easy for the browser to animate at a high frame rate. In your case, for movement, animate the `transform: translate()` property.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) are the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it. I added some updated code, the animations are a lot better, but still a little bit jittery. Can you see anything wrong that I may have missed or misunderstood?

Comment: Also here is another good article I found: https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108